# Blender bump disappears at certain angle

Tags: 3d, blender

I am new to blender and learning new stuffs. I have created model of ruins of pillars and I wanted to create stone texture over it. So I used noise texture along with math node to bump to make it look like stone. In render mode it looks fine for particular angle. When I try to rotate model at certain place bump disappears. Is it only solvable by displacing vertices randomly to create bumps? Is there a better way to make it look good in all angles?

FYI using blender 2.93

Attaching video clip which shows the problem I am facing and shader node used to create bump on model image:

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask it on [blender.se].

Comment: This can be a problem of [under-sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), or sampling at the [same frequency than the noise generator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/noise.html#notes).